# Recover access logs of AWS before activate ClouldTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to recover the access logins of my AWS account before 7 days and before the activation of the ClouldTrail?

I need to know all the IPs that accessed my account in all 2017.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS does provide that information for compliance reasons. You need to file a support ticket with premium support.

This is based on the forum information that login information is collected even before activating cloudtrail.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=653867

Comment: Do u know if they record ssh access of ec2 instances?

Comment: I don't think it is aws responsibility to record those logins. Anything you do with that is the responsibility of the account. Also only the EC2 is a cloud service, not what you do with it. Support might have better answer.